# Android BMI calculator error with datatypes

Tags: java, android, integer

I think my issue is with datatypes, but I'm not sure.
I have been playing around with this for hours now.

Here is my code:

```
    Integer height, weight;
    double BMI = ((weight / height)/height);
```

height is taken in metres, and weight in kilograms and it is assigned a value from the sharepreferences.

Please can someone help me?

Comment: Use Integer for whole numbers and double which will contain a decimal. Metres would surely be something like 1.x? In which case, an Integer isn't suitable? Stacktrace needed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Casting one of the variables should work fine.

Like that:

```
Integer height, weight;
double BMI = (weight / (double)height)/height;
```